# Having problems on fetching variables on a class in PHP

Tags: php

I just want to ask if its possible to call variables on class to another page of the site. I have tried calling the function's name and inside the parenthesis. I included the variable found inside that function e.g:

```
<?php 
  $loadconv -> loadmsg($msgReturn);
  echo $loadconv;
?>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide some more code, such as the class definition and the object instantiation? Also you do `'$string'` but that literally means `$string`. No need for the single quotes.

Comment: sorry about that.. Ive edited my post

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
class Load
{
    public $msgReturn;

    __construct() 
    {

    }

    public function loadMsg($param)
    {
        $this->msgReturn = $param;
    }       
}
```

Then you could do

```
$loadConv = new Load();
$loadConv->loadMsg('just a string');
echo $loadConv->msgReturn; // 'just a string'
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what im looking for.. =)